# Joint 2D/1D sequence to 2D sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I need to solve the following problem:

Say we have a ball in a box, bouncing around. Each T_ball, I get the image of the ball within the box. Each T_occlusions, I get the max of the image along x or y axis (That is, without noise, I would have the x or y location of the ball).

Typically, T_occlusions << T_ball. I would like to obtain a sort of movement prediction of the ball, as an image, every T_occlusions.

Let us consider for now that T_occlusions and T_ball are constant.

This situation is represented below, for T_occlusions = T_ball/2.

[image: White ball position is referenced by the occlusion vector (blue : occluded, white : free)]

I can already predict the next frame without using the Occlusions, via a 4 layer ConvLSTM network in Keras.

How can I join the 1D/2D data together ?

I thought of the following:

- Upsample the images (For every Occlusion, consider the last input image), and add a scalar to the vector, indicating the time since last known image. This should solve the frequency mismatch while telling the network that the input image isn't brand new.
- Upsample the occlusions, as to create a second depth for the image, and feed that to the ConvLSTM

How could I train the network to produce correct in-between images, based only on a ground truth every T_ball ?

Could I consider training on input sequence : (I0,O0),(I0,O1),(I1,O2),(I1,O3), and expect it to give out I2 ?

Is there any network that I could use ? Maybe two separate networks, exchanging information (One LSTM, and one ConvLSTM)?

Finally, the T_ball is not really constant, and varies within a sequence, and between sequences. I thought of either up/down sampling it to fit my network. Is there no other way ? Could I choose sequences to be of the same pattern within each batch, and hope for the best ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Have you considered a Kalman filter?

Comment: @Jonas I have, but I believe a ML approach would give better results. I'd like to try :)

Comment: Hm, why learn the model when you already know it from physics? Also, you could be right :D

Comment: Because this dataset is meant to prove the feasibility of the model, and then I aim at using the model for a way harder problem, where, obviously, the physics are unknown.